# Update MongoDB collection toLowercase for array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have already seen these two posts

[Update MongoDB collection using $toLower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423932/update-mongodb-collection-using-tolower)

and

[To loop through non associative array in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476697/to-loop-through-non-associative-array-in-mongodb)

But those didn't helped me.

I have a collection with few documents like this:

```
{
"_id": "58bda97de000ae205f77c6e0",

"artistName": "ABC",

"trackNames": [
"1A",
"1B",
"1C",
"1D"
],
}
```

I want to change all the values of trackNames field to lowercase.Like this:

```
{
    "_id": "58bda97de000ae205f77c6e0",

    "artistName": "ABC",

    "trackNames": [
    "1a",
    "1b",
    "1c",
    "1d"
    ],
    }
```

Till now I tried like this:

```
db.artist.find().forEach(function(e) {
e.trackNames.forEach(function(i){
i=i.toLowerCase();
db.artist.save(e)})})
```

But its not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i = i.toLowerCase()` does not actually update the object. Instead you can replace the array itself with a map:

```
e.trackNames = e.trackNames.map(function (trackName) {
  return trackName.toLowerCase();
});
```

This will update the trackNames array on the original object which you can then save.

Comment: thanks.It helped. I never used map before. new thing to learn.

Comment: @Arijit `.map` iterates over an array and returns a new array with the values you return from the callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map